# How to convert a JIRA task to a subtask from Atlassian Python API?

Tags: python, jira, atlassian-python-api

I'm trying to convert a JIRA issue to a subtask

That's what I'm doing:

```
converted_to_subtask = jira.update_issue_field(
    "FSTORE-326", {
        "issuetype": {"name": "Sub-task"}, "parent": {"key": "FSTORE-324"}
    })
```

Alas, I get an error 400.

What is the correct way to convert a JIRA task to subtask from Atlassian Python API?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Jira API does not support this operation yet.

Sources:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-27893
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-27893